# entity_load() not listing custom fields.

Tags: entities

I created the custom field for existing entity, I can see those fields listed on '`field_info_instances()`' . And I also have data in those fields, but I can't see those fields listed on the entity object returned by  `entity_load()`.

This is how I am installing the fields

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N()
 */
function dashboard_update_7002() { 

        field_create_field( array(
            'field_name' => "dashboard_url",
            'type' => 'text',
            'cardinality' => 1,
            'entity_types' => array('manufacturer'),
            'translatable' => TRUE,
            'locked' => true,
        ));

        field_create_instance(array(
            'field_name' => "dashboard_url",
            'entity_type' => 'manufacturer',
            'bundle' => 'manufacturer',
            'label' => "Dasboard URL",
            'required' => FALSE,
            'widget' => array(
                'type' => 'text_textfield',
            )
        ));

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head for a while, I found the solution. On the module where that entity was defined '`hook_entity_info()`', '`fieldable`' property was missing which is set to `FALSE` by default. Therefore none of the fields were being attached to that entity.